# useEffect API calls making modal of Chakra UI closed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my below code, I'm sending an API call after 30 seconds to update a entry in column in my table (see that `useEffect`), when that API gets hits, this reprocess modal gets closed but it shouldn't be doing that.

Jobs.tsx

```
 const columns = [
columnHelper.accessor("jobTitle", {
  id: "jobTitle",
  header: () => "Job Title",
  cell: (info) => {
    const category = info.row.original.category;
    let icon = null;
    if (category && category.category) {
      if (category.category === "Tire") {
        icon = (
          <Tooltip
            label={category.category}
            shouldWrapChildren
            placement="left"
          >
            <Icon as={GiFlatTire} mr={2} fontSize="xl" color="gray.500" />
          </Tooltip>
        );
      } else if (category.category === "Construction And Renovation") {
        <Tooltip
          label={category.category}
          shouldWrapChildren
          placement="left"
        >
          <Icon as={MdConstruction} mr={2} fontSize="xl" color="gray.500" />
        </Tooltip>;
      }
    } else {
      icon = (
        <Tooltip label="No Company" shouldWrapChildren placement="left">
          <Icon
            as={BsFillPersonFill}
            mr={2}
            fontSize="xl"
            color="gray.500"
          />
        </Tooltip>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Flex alignItems="center">
        {icon}
        <JobDetailsLink
          job={info.row.original}
          text={info.getValue()}
          showVideo
          showVideoModal={showVideoModal}
        />
      </Flex>
    );
  },
}),
columnHelper.accessor("jobName", {
  id: "jobName",
  header: () => "Job Name",
  cell: (info) => (
    <JobDetailsLink job={info.row.original} text={info.getValue()} />
  ),
}),
columnHelper.accessor("createdOn", {
  id: "createdOn",
  header: () => "Date",
  cell: (info) => format(parseISO(info.getValue()), "MMM d, yyyy"),
}),
columnHelper.accessor("jobStatus", {
  id: "jobStatus",
  header: () => "Job Status",
  cell: (info) => jobStatusMap[info.getValue() as keyof StatusMapType],
}),
columnHelper.display({
  id: "actions",
  header: () => <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Actions</div>,
  cell: (props) => <ActionMenu job={props.row.original} />,
}),
];

 useEffect(() => {
   const intervalCall = setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(getJobStatuses());
  }, 30000);
  return () => {
   clearInterval(intervalCall);
 };
}, []);

  useEffect(() => {
 const intervalCall = setInterval(() => {
   dispatch(getJobStatuses());
  }, 30000);

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams({
  jobTitle: jobTitleSearch,
  fromDate,
  toDate,
  page: (pageIndex + 1).toString(),
});
const newUrl = `${window.location.pathname}?${searchParams.toString()}`;
window.history.replaceState(null, "", newUrl);
return () => {
  clearInterval(intervalCall);
 };
}, [pagination]);
```

jobSlice.ts

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { RootState } from "../store";
import { GetAllJobs, UpdateStatus } from "../utils/api";
import httpClient from "../utils/httpClient";
import { DeviceInfo } from "./deviceSlice";

type JobsSearchParam = {
  pageIndex: number | string;
  pageSize: number | string;
  jobNameSearch: string;
  jobTitleSearch: string;



startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
};

export type FileType = {
  createdOn: string;
  filePath: string;
  id: string;
  updatedOn: string;
  name: string;
  data?: Array<{ marker1: string; marker2: string; distance: number }>;
};
export type Job = {
  id: string;
  calFiles: Array<FileType>;
  configFile: Array<FileType>;
  createdOn: string;
  images: Array<FileType>;
  jobName: string;
  jobStatus: string | undefined;
  jobTitle: string;
  masks: Array<FileType>;
  mobileCameraInfo: Array<DeviceInfo>;
  requestId: number;
  updatedOn: string;
  videos: Array<FileType>;
};
type JobsState = {
  jobs: Array<Job>;
  status: string;
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;
  totalPages: number;
  totalElements: number;
  jobNameSearch: string;
  jobTitleSearch: string;
  isSearching: boolean;
};

type JobStatus = {
  id: string;
  jobStatus: string;
};

export const fetchJobs = createAsyncThunk(
  "jobs/fetchJobs",
  async (
    {
      pageIndex,
      pageSize,
      jobNameSearch,
      jobTitleSearch,
      startDate,
      endDate,
    }: JobsSearchParam,
    { rejectWithValue }
  ) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await httpClient(
        `${GetAllJobs}/all?page=${pageIndex}&size=${pageSize}&sort=createdOn,desc&jobName=${
          jobNameSearch || ""
        }&jobTitle=${
          jobTitleSearch || ""
        }&startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`,
        "GET"
      );

      return data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

export const getJobStatuses = createAsyncThunk(
  "jobs/fetchJobsStatuses",
  async (arg, { getState }) => {
    const { jobs } = getState() as RootState;
    let jobIdsArray = jobs.jobs.map((job: Job) => job.id);
    try {
      const { data } = await httpClient(`${UpdateStatus}`, "POST", jobIdsArray);
      return data;
    } catch (e: any) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
);

const initialState: JobsState = {
  jobs: [],
  status: "idle",
  pageIndex: 0,
  pageSize: 8,
  totalPages: 0,
  totalElements: 0,
  jobNameSearch: "",
  jobTitleSearch: "",
  isSearching: false,
};
const jobsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "jobs",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setIsSearching: (state, action) => {
      state.isSearching = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchJobs.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchJobs.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "succeeded";
      const { totalElements, content, totalPages } = action.payload;
      state.jobs = content;
      state.totalPages = totalPages;
      state.isSearching = false;
      state.totalElements = totalElements;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchJobs.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed";
      state.isSearching = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(getJobStatuses.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "succeeded";
      let currentJobsIds = state.jobs.map((job) => job.id);
      let jobStatuses: Array<JobStatus> = action.payload;
      let matchingJobs = jobStatuses.filter((status) =>
        currentJobsIds.includes(status.id)
      );
      state.jobs = state.jobs.map((job: Job) => ({
        ...job,
        jobStatus: matchingJobs.find((matchJob) => matchJob.id === job.id)
          ?.jobStatus,
      }));
    });
  },
});

export const selectAllJobs = (state: RootState) => state.jobs.jobs;
export const selectJobsStatus = (state: RootState) => state.jobs.status;
export const selectTotalPages = (state: RootState) => state.jobs.totalPages;
export const selectIsSearching = (state: RootState) => state.jobs.isSearching;
export const selectTotalElements = (state: RootState) =>
  state.jobs.totalElements;

export const { setIsSearching } = jobsSlice.actions;

export default jobsSlice.reducer;
```

When I click actions i get this option of reprocess in ActionMenuJob.tsx

```
  import {
  Box,
  Icon,
  Menu,
  MenuButton,
  MenuItem,
  MenuList,
  useDisclosure
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {
  MdEdit,
  MdMoreHoriz,
  MdOutlineFileDownload,
  MdOutlineVisibility,
  MdRestore
} from "react-icons/md";
import {
  GrPowerCycle
} from "react-icons/gr";
import {
  BsFillPersonFill
} from "react-icons/bs";
import { BiTrash } from "react-icons/bi";
import { FileType, Job } from "../features/jobsSlice";
import { DownloadFolder } from "../utils/api";
import { downloadFromURL } from "../utils/fileUtils";
import { generateEndPoint } from "../utils/httpClient";
import Reprocess from "./job/reprocess/Reprocess";
import DeleteReprocessedJob from "./job/reprocess/DeleteReprocessedJob";
import SelectCustomerData from "./job/reprocess/SelectCustomerData";
import RecoverReprocessedJob from "./job/reprocess/RecoverReprocessedJob";

type ActionMenuProps = {
  job: Job;
};

const fileTypes = ["images", "videos", "pickleFiles", "yamlFile"];

function ActionMenu({ job }: ActionMenuProps) {
  const { jobTitle, jobName, jobStatus, images } = job;
  const checkDirectoryForImages = images;
  const showHideFileOption =
    jobStatus === "ON_HOLD" ||
    jobStatus === "JOB_FAILED" ||
    jobStatus === "COMPLETED";

  var newUpdatedJobTitleAndName = jobTitle + "_" + jobName;

  const generateDownloadFolderURL = (fileType: string) => {
    const path = `${newUpdatedJobTitleAndName}/${fileType}`;
    const exclude = fileTypes
      .filter((type) => type !== fileType)
      .map((type) => `${newUpdatedJobTitleAndName}/${type}`)
      .join();

    const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo") as any);
    const authToken = userInfo?.authToken;

    const downloadFolder = `${DownloadFolder}?path=${path}&fileName=${jobName}&exclude=${exclude}&bucketName=dev-rc-2-0&authToken=${authToken}`;

    return downloadFolder;
  };

  const downloadZipFolder = (fileType: string) => {
    const url = generateEndPoint(generateDownloadFolderURL(fileType));

    downloadFromURL(url);
  };

  const downloadIcon = <Icon as={MdOutlineFileDownload} boxSize={5} mr={1} />;
  const reprocessIcon = <Icon as={GrPowerCycle} boxSize={4} mr={1} />;
  const customerIcon = <Icon as={BsFillPersonFill} boxSize={4} mr={1} />;
  const deleteIcon = <Icon as={BiTrash} boxSize={4} mr={1} />;
  const recoverIcon = <Icon as={MdRestore} boxSize={4} mr={1} />;
  const editIcon = <Icon as={MdEdit} boxSize={5} mr={1} />;
  const viewIcon = <Icon as={MdOutlineVisibility} boxSize={5} mr={1} />;

  const {
    isOpen: isReprocessModalOpen,
    onOpen: onReprocessModalOpen,
    onClose: onReprocessModalClose
  } = useDisclosure();

  const {
    isOpen: isDeleteModalOpen,
    onOpen: onDeleteModalOpen,
    onClose: onDeleteModalClose
  } = useDisclosure();

  const {
    isOpen: isForCustomerModalOpen,
    onOpen: onForCustomerModalOpen,
    onClose: onForCustomerModalClose
  } = useDisclosure();

  const {
    isOpen: isRecoverModalOpen,
    onOpen: onRecoverModalOpen,
    onClose: onRecoverModalClose
  } = useDisclosure();

  return (
    <Box textAlign="center">
      <Menu>
        <MenuButton>
          <Icon boxSize={6} as={MdMoreHoriz} />
        </MenuButton>
        <MenuList>
          {/* <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
            <Icon as={MdRemoveRedEye} boxSize={5} mr={1} />
            Open Directory
          </MenuItem> */}
          <MenuItem onClick={onReprocessModalOpen}>
            {reprocessIcon}
            Reprocess
          </MenuItem>
          {/* <MenuItem onClick={onDeleteModalOpen}>
            {deleteIcon}
            Delete Job
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={onRecoverModalOpen}>
            {recoverIcon}
            Recover Job
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={onForCustomerModalOpen}>
            {customerIcon}
            For Customer
          </MenuItem> */}
          {checkDirectoryForImages.length ? (
            <MenuItem onClick={() => downloadZipFolder("images")}>
              {downloadIcon}
              Download Images
            </MenuItem>
          ) : (
            <MenuItem onClick={() => downloadZipFolder("videos")}>
              {downloadIcon}
              Download Videos
            </MenuItem>
          )}
          {/* <MenuItem onClick={() => downloadZipFolder("yamlFile")}>
            {downloadIcon}
            Download Yaml File
          </MenuItem> */}
          {/* <MenuItem>
            <Link to={`/yaml?path=${configFile[0].filePath}`}>
              {editIcon}
              Edit Yaml File
            </Link>
          </MenuItem> */}
          {showHideFileOption && (
            <MenuItem onClick={() => downloadZipFolder("output")}>
              {downloadIcon}
              Download Output Files
            </MenuItem>
          )}
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>
      <Reprocess
        isOpen={isReprocessModalOpen}
        onClose={onReprocessModalClose}
        job={job}
      />
      <DeleteReprocessedJob
        isOpen={isDeleteModalOpen}
        onClose={onDeleteModalClose}
        job={job}
      />
      <RecoverReprocessedJob
        isOpen={isRecoverModalOpen}
        onClose={onRecoverModalClose}
        job={job}
      />
      <SelectCustomerData
        isOpen={isForCustomerModalOpen}
        onClose={onForCustomerModalClose}
        job={job}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default ActionMenu;
```

Popup code

```
import {
Box,
Button,
Modal,
ModalBody,
ModalCloseButton,
ModalContent,
ModalFooter,
ModalOverlay,
Text,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import LoadYamlFile from "./LoadYamlFile";
import { Job } from "../../../features/jobsSlice";
import { useState } from "react";
import InputParameters from "./InputParameters";
import Stepper from "react-stepper-horizontal";

type ReprocessProps = {
    isOpen: boolean;
    job: Job;
    onClose: () => void;
};

function Reprocess({
    isOpen,
    job,
    onClose
}: ReprocessProps) {
const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);

const [yamlData, setYamlData] = useState("");
console.log(yamlData)

function handleNext() {
    setCurrentStep(2);
}

function handleBack() {
    setCurrentStep(1);
}

function handleClose() {
    setYamlData("");
    onClose();
}

const steps = [
    { title: "Load YAML file" },
    { title: "Input Parameters" },
];

return (
    <Modal closeOnOverlayClick={false} isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} size="5xl">
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
            <ModalBody>
                <Box mb={4}>
                    <Stepper
                        steps={steps}
                        activeStep={currentStep - 1}
                        completeColor="#38A169"
                        circleFontSize={14}
                        titleFontSize={16}
                    />
                </Box>
                {currentStep == 1 && <LoadYamlFile job={job} yamlData={yamlData} setYamlData={setYamlData} />}
                {currentStep == 2 && <InputParameters job={job} />}
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                {currentStep == 1 && (
                    <>
                        <Button onClick={handleNext} colorScheme="blue">
                            Next
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose} ml={3}>Cancel</Button>
                    </>
                )}
                {currentStep == 2 && (
                    <>
                        <Button onClick={handleBack} colorScheme="blue">
                            Back
                        </Button>
                        <Button ml={3} colorScheme="blue">
                            Reprocess
                        </Button>
                    </>
                )}
            </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
    </Modal >
    );
}

export default Reprocess;
```